# How do I find the proportion of a value in a variable on R?

Tags: r, statistics

I want to find how many people who were surveyed for HIV tested negative.

I have an objective titled as HIV. Where HIV=0 is people who are negative. HIV=1, 2, 3, 4 are different levels of viral load of all people who tested positive.

I want to know of all people who are under the HIV objective, how many have HIV = 0?

I especially want to know how to calculate this value when there are missing values. TIA.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `mean(HIV == 0, na.rm = TRUE)` for proportion and `sum(HIV == 0, na.rm = TRUE)` for count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is a `vector` called `HIV`:

```
HIV <- rep(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA), each = 4)
```

Which looks like this:

```
 [1]  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4 NA NA NA NA
```

You can use the following:

```
prop.table(table(Data)))
```

To get an `table` object like this:

```
HIV
  0   1   2   3   4 
0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

Comment: does that automatically remove missing values?

Comment: I edited the post so you can see the outputs. Let me know if this answer doesn't solve your questions

Comment: so I think I was overcomplicating it and it does in fact consider those missing values. Thank you <333

Comment: Nice! Since this answer your question, please consider to accept my answer (clicking the check icon). This would help others with the same problem to find a solution :D

Comment: @sam.cold Missings are removed, to include them in the output use `prop.table(table(Data), useNA='ifany'))`. Note that `prop.table` is the old name which is kept for back-compatibility, we should use `proportions` now.

Comment: I didn't know about the `proportions` function. Thank you!